# Is it correct to use PHP namespace declaration in 2 separate scripts?

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm learning about PHP namespaces. I'm attempting to add a namespace to a class I wrote, and then reference it in another script. I've done it like this:

**MenuBuilder.php**

```
namespace Andytest\MenuBuilder;

class MenuBuilder {

    public function test() {
        echo 'testing';
    }
}
```

**test.php** (where the class is used)

```
namespace Andytest\MenuBuilder;

require_once 'MenuBuilder.php';

$Builder = new MenuBuilder;
$Builder->test();
```

The output from this is as I expect - it outputs the word 'testing' when I run test.php.

But I'm not sure why I need `namespace Andytest\MenuBuilder` in test.php because it's already decleared in MenuBuilder.php, which is being required by test.php? If I remove the `namespace` line in test.php it doesn't work.

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: In test.php you should have `use Andytest\MenuBuilder\MenuBuilder;` instead of `namespace Andytest\MenuBuilder;`

Comment: @Neat I've tried your suggestion, and it also works. This is why I'm finding it confusing though because both approaches give the same result, so hard to know what is correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thats because when you do namespace instead of use the file expects your `new MenuBuilder` to be in the same namespace, which it is, and it wont throw a conflict, try changing the namespace in test.php and it'll throw an error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `test.php` you should have `use Andytest\MenuBuilder\MenuBuilder;` instead of `namespace Andytest\MenuBuilder;`

Because you use `namespace` instead of `use` the file expects every class you create that is not specified in the `use` case to be in the same namespace, therefore `new MenuBuilder();` actually calls `new Andytest\MenuBuilder\MenuBuilder();`.

If you would change the `namespace` in `test.php` it should tell you that it cant find `MenuBuilder`